# Recommendation for graphic card

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, hardware

My CPU is Pentium G2020 running on Gigabyte H61M-S2P motherboard with 8GB DDR3 ram. 
I want to upgrade for faster rendering without adding additional RAM on my machine or changing the processor. 
Please suggest a suitable graphic card.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware recommendation

Comment: @Nimish welcome to the site. Questions about hardware recommendations are considered off topic Please take the [tour] and read through the topics on the [help] section to understand how to make better use of this site

Answer (score 2):

For the record, RAM doesn't affect render times. If you would like to know which graphics card you should buy for rendering, i suggest visiting http://blenchmark.com. Here you have a full list of all the benchmarks on almost all the consumer CPUs and GPUs.

edit: typo